# How to set all columns as rows in first column on a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and it has 35 columns so I cannot clearly get a view of all columns on this table. It looks like below.

[image]

Then I decided to get all columns into first column as rows. But I haven't any clear idea how to do this using table properties.

How to set all columns as rows in first column on a `JTable`?

Comment: It's not really something that `JTable`'s designed for, you're going to have to supply your own "row header", maybe someting like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248084/how-to-display-row-header-on-jtable-instead-of-column-header/26248635#26248635)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer :- How could I use your advice for a JTable from NetBeans Palette ?

Comment: You can't, the problem you have is far too complex to be solved through "form editors" alone, you will need to get your hands dirty. Now, because `TableWithRowHeader` extends `JTable`, it means you can drag it onto the form

Comment: @MadProgrammer : In your example , you didn't feed any data to the table . But I use a for loop to feed some data .

Comment: @MadProgrammer :-  So , how do you change your example for feed data to the table ?

Comment: Use a `TableModel` like you should, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details